# How to deal the poor bumblebee performance?

Tags: linux, nvidia, archlinux, optimus

I'm using Archlinux, kernel 4.12, bumblebee 3.2.1, nvidia driver 382.

When I run the `optirun glxgears` and `vblank_mode=0 primusrun glxgears`, the max FPS is near 3400.

But when I run the `glxgears` directly with NVIDIA Driver, the max FPS is near 20000.

I don't know what's wrong. Is there better solution than bumblebee or some way to deal this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am using this optimus technology with archlinux for two years now. The only way to get max performance (for now) is to use 
`vblank_mode=0 optirun -b primus` . There is no other way to get a better performance for now!